# Can't login to Mahara

Tags: mahara

I have a problem with one user. This user can't login to Mahara. At every attempt to login he sees this 2 messages (see the image below):

- You have exceeded the maximum login attempts. This account has been locked for up to 5 minutes.
- You have not provided the correct credentials to log in. Please check your username and password are correct.

In the first message is written to wait 5 minutes, but it doesn't matter how long he waits (1 hr, 1 day ...) he gets always this message. I have also changed the user password... Nothing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a cron job to trigger Mahara's cron job script solved the problem. [Here](https://mahara.org/interaction/forum/topic.php?id=4832) is a forum thread (with more details) regarding this issue.

UPDATE

This issue is due to the fact that the column `logintries` from table `usr` for the corresponding user has reached the maximum allowed value. Thus resetting this column value to 0 will solve the problem. This can be done manually using SQL or by running Mahara's cron (recommended).

1. SQL solution: `UPDATE usr SET logintries=0` (for all users) or `UPDATE usr SET logintries=0 WHERE username = 'yourusername'` (for a specific user). But this is a short-term solution because you'll have to run it every time you'll encounter this issue.
2. Cron job solution: for an immediate result one can run Mahara's cron job directly in browser by accessing `http://your-mahara-site.org/lib/cron.php`. But the execution of mahara's cron should be automated by adding a corresponding record in crontab, see [System Administrator's Guide/Cron Job](https://wiki.mahara.org/wiki/System_Administrator%27s_Guide/Cron_Job).

Comment: Your post is useful. But, if you would have added some steps in your answers, it might have worked for us.